# Bootstrap navbar dropdown wont collapse in IOS10

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I have a piece of code, which works perfectly in desktop browsers, in android browsers, on iphone browsers.
It works if ios version < 10.
But Bootstrap dropdown button doesn't collapse when I click on it, if ios version - 10 :

Two upper buttons:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDIW7.jpg)

Source code: http://pastebin.com/NaJKD97w

Thank you